# Convert HH:mm:ss into Millisecond in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date

From the payload I am trying to send a time in HH:mm:ss format. I would like to return this in millisecond.

Below I was able to convert  the date with it (with the help of SO).

```
String myDate = "2018/11/13 12:00:00";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") );
long millis = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();  
System.out.println(millis);
```

I need to convert HH:mm:ss to milliseconds

If I pass in 12:30:00, I need the millisecond of that... TODAYs millisecond

Comment: Not sure on the question? You need the date AND the time to find the epoch-millis. Are you only interested in finding the millis from the start of day (?)

Comment: So, you want to convert 12:00:00 to ms? (12*60*60+00*60+00)*1000

Comment: what are you actually looking for? the question isn't very much clear on that aspect! what is *TODAYs millisecond*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [LocalTime.toSecondOfDay()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toSecondOfDay())

```
String myDate = "2018/11/13 12:00:00";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") );
int millis = localDateTime.toLocalTime().toSecondOfDay() * 1000;
```

> im not passing in the date. im passing in the time

Even in this case, LocalTime is the one you're looking for.

```
String time "12:30:00";
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time);
int millis = localTime.toSecondOfDay() * 1000;
```

Comment: this is not what I need...please see again.

Comment: @DroiDev You wrote: "I need to convert HH:mm:ss to milliseconds". That code does it. If that's not what you want, please update your question.

Comment: im not passing in the date. im passing in the time.

Comment: This correctly answers the question that OP asked.  If it's not what OP wants, then he/she needs to ask a different question.

Comment: If all that is being passed is "HH:mm:ss", then change `LocalDateTime` to `LocalTime`, and the `LocalTime.parse(incomingTime)` should be sufficient to parse. But that is a trivial modification.

Comment: Localtime.parse requires API level 26.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `LocalTime`:

```
LocalTime zero = LocalTime.parse("00:00:00");
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("13:15:10");
Long mils = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(zero, time);
System.out.print(mils);
```

will print:

```
47710000
```

or simpler, courtesy of @OleV.V.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("13:15:10");
Long mils = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, time);
System.out.print(mils);
```

Comment: It can be done this simply. As a detail instead of `zero` you may use `LocalDate.MIDNIGHT`.

Comment: java.time does contain quite a few handy constants. `Instant.EPOCH` and `ZoneOffset.UTC` are probably good to know too. They’re all in the documentation, of course.